# UITableView - How to check whether a section footer is visible completely on screen and scroll accordingly to make section footer visible completely?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In `UICollectionView` with multiple sections, I can

1. Check whether a section footer is visible completely on screen.
2. If it doesn't, I will perform scrolling, to make the footer visible completely.

Here's my code snippet to achieve so.

```
private func ensureSectionFooterIsVisibleIfPossible(_ section: Int) {
    //
    // Ensure footer is visible.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201646/uicollectionview-scroll-to-any-footer-or-header-view/31250801
    //
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)

    if let layoutAttributes =  collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, at: indexPath) {
        var visibleRect: CGRect = CGRect()
        visibleRect.origin = collectionView.contentOffset
        visibleRect.size = collectionView.bounds.size
        
        let footerRect = layoutAttributes.frame

        //
        // Is this section footer visible completely on screen?
        //
        if !visibleRect.contains(footerRect) {
            //
            // If not, scroll till the section footer visible completely.
            //
            var resultOffset : CGPoint = collectionView.contentOffset
            resultOffset.y = (footerRect.origin.y + footerRect.size.height) - (collectionView.contentInset.top + collectionView.frame.size.height)
            collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: resultOffset, size: collectionView.frame.size), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the similar behavior in `UITableView`? As, I do not find an equivalent `collectionView.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement` in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rectForFooter method

```
var visibleRect: CGRect = CGRect()
visibleRect.origin = tableview.contentOffset
visibleRect.size = tableview.bounds.size
            
let footerRect = tableview.rectForFooter(inSection: 0)

// Is this section footer visible completely on screen?

if !visibleRect.contains(footerRect) {

// If not, scroll till the section footer visible completely.

}
```